# Simple Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, haml

I want to code simple app, with index and about page, without using db, all text will be in views. But I can't call my controller methods, to change view. 
Here is controller (home_controller.rb)

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def about
  end

end
```

layout:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Title
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    .wrapper
      = yield
      .footer
```

home index view:

```
%h2 Index
%h1
  This is example page
%p
  = link_to "Home", root_path
  = link_to "About", :controller => "home", :action => "index"
%p
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

about view:

```
%h2 About
%h1
  This is about page
%p
  = link_to "Home", root_path
  = link_to "About", :controller => "home", :action => "about"
%p
  Lorem ipsum
```

in routes.rb I have `root :to => 'home#index'`

when i call my domain, i'll get index, when i write: domain/home/index   I get

> No route matches [GET] "/home/index"

when I call about, it's the same, how can I call my pages? 
rake routes give me:

> root  / {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define those routes as well. They won't appear automatically.

For example, here's what you can find in default generated routes.rb (at the end).

```
  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Uncomment this and you should be able to access `/home/index` and `/home/about`.

Comment: Template is missing

Missing template home/about, application/about with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/mnt/_Projects/exapmle2/app/views"         wtf?   i have this one

Comment: Do you have `/app/views/home/about.html.haml`?

Comment: ofc I have, hm this is interesting

Comment: Well, there must be something wrong elsewhere. Did you restart your server (just in case)?

Comment: i simple create other scaffold, and deleted what i didn't needed

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your routes file above the `root :to => ...` line

```
get 'home/index'
get 'home/about'
```

Comment: Are you sure about backslashes? :)